# How to colorize an image with HTML5-Canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

how can I colorize an Image with HTML5-Canvas?
Based on an Hex- or RGB- Color Value as input?

Comment: I didn't understand, you want something like a "fill" tool in editors?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/).

The Colorize filter looks like exactly what you want: http://camanjs.com/docs/filters.html#section-13

> Uniformly shifts the colors in an
>   image towards the given color.
>
> The adjustment range is from 0 to 100.
>   The higher the value, the closer the
>   colors in the image shift towards the
>   given adjustment color.

```
Caman("#image", function () {
    // Explicitly give the R, G, and B values of the
    // color to shift towards.
    //
    // Arguments: (R, G, B, strength)
    this.colorize(25, 180, 200, 20);

    // The other way is to specify a color in hex form:
    this.colorize("#4090D5", 20);
});
```

For more examples of built in filters: http://camanjs.com/guides/#BuiltIn

Comment: I also had to adjust the brightness when using a black and white icon: this.brightness(50).render();

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/).

- http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/coloradjust/
- http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/hsl/

Comment: Did I understand right that I have to use -1 or +1 with that library?
What I want is to define a color and the canvas colorizes that image, like a greyscale image is colorized to #0000ff (blue).

Comment: Well, you'd need some extra code to transform a hex color input into the right arguments to pass to Pixastic.

Comment: Pixtastic colorization does NOT work with IE9. I also found that it no colorization option. To actually set a color, set the color to 1,1,1 first, then reget the image context, then set it to whatever color you want.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [Tancolor](https://github.com/nicolaisi/tancolor). This is a lightweight jquery plugin to just colorize an image. You can tryout combination on the [interactive page](http://nicolaisi.github.io/tancolor/).