# How to colorize a PNG image, cross-browser, using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, png, colorize

I'm trying to do the same as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6498720/1544337), but more basic: I have a PNG image with only white and transparent as colors. I need to colorize the white part, without touching the transparent part, in a given RGB hex value.

I'd like to do this with a jQuery plugin. Is there any that can do this?

It has to work in the latest versions of all major browser (IE, FF, GC, Safari), with bonus points for lower version support as well.

---

#### Example usage

[image] [image] [image]

---

Things I found / thought of already:

- [Pixastic](http://www.pixastic.com/lib/docs/actions/coloradjust/), but that doesn't have cross-broswer support
- [CamanJS](http://camanjs.com/docs/filters.html#section-13), but that isn't for jQuery
- Overlaying with another div  like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4416015/1544337), but that would harm the transparent parts
- Making the white parts transparent and vice versa, and then use a background-color - but the images are uploaded by the user and this wouldn't make it more user friendly

Comment: Are you looking for the "result" to be an actually modified PNG image or just for the result to be rendered correctly on a page?

Comment: @Caleb the latter would be sufficient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using SVG instead? SVG is [supported in all major browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg) since IE 9. As a text-based format, it's small, lightweight, and easy to manipulate.

A quick-and-dirty approach is to use [SVG-edit](http://svg-edit.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/editor/svg-editor.html) (online) or [Inkscape](http://inkscape.org/) (download) to create your drawing, then simply drop the resulting `<svg>` element onto your HTML page. Here's a fiddle showing how that could work: http://jsfiddle.net/t6fAb/

---

Better yet, use [SVG.js](http://www.svgjs.com/) to create the drawing entirely in JavaScript. Here's a fiddle showing how that could work: http://jsfiddle.net/WEL4J/